# Advice for Beginner Python learner (not in CS) taking an advanced CS course (requires good knowledge of Python)

Tags: python

I'm taking an graduate course that requires good knowledge of Python. I'm not a CS major, and I just started coding in Python. What's your advice on being able to complete homeworks? Are there any tips to come over the (very) steep learning curve? Should I take the time for beginner tutorials?

There's a lot of tutorials out there and I'm not sure how much I need to do in order to be ready for the material. Also, the course already started so I would need to do a lot of these in a short period of time.

Comment: Definitely take the time for beginner tutorials - there is no easy way to learn programming. Learning the basics will save you huge amounts of time and lessen then amount of headaches that you will encounter.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is off-topic for SO, but I will offer an answer. I never took a single CS course, yet have been a professional developer for many years now. My advice is a question, do you have a genuine interest in how computers work?

If so, you can find a way to learn what you need to know. When I started my journey, I made $9/hr and spent any extra time and money in bookstores, buying the few books I could afford that seemed most relevant. Nowadays, you have much more information available and most of it for free. So, if you have a genuine interest you can learn what you need to know. Forget classes and grades, it's whether you can solve a problem that counts.

I would say good luck, but it's dedication that you need.